# Element <div id="password" is not reachable by keyboard

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to log into a website that requires credentials.  I'm getting the following error on the password page:

```
ElementNotInteractableException: Element <div id="password" class="rFrNMe KSczvd uyaebd BlbNGe zKHdkd sdJrJc Tyc9J"> is not reachable by keyboard
```

Here is the offender.

[image]

Is there any work-around?  I Googled for a solution on SO and saw some comments about Java.  I'm using Python, and I haven't found anything that works.  Here is all my code.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from selenium import webdriver
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.accept_untrusted_certs = True
import time
import requests
import urllib.request
import pandas as pd  

    
wd = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="C:/Utility/geckodriver.exe", firefox_profile=profile)
url = 'https://intra-net-website.com/'
wd.get(url)

# set username
time.sleep(2)
username = wd.find_element_by_id("identifierId")
username.send_keys("first.last@gmail.com")
wd.find_element_by_id("identifierNext").click()

# error occurs here
# set password
time.sleep(2)
password = wd.find_element_by_id("password")
password.send_keys("my_password")
wd.find_element_by_id("passwordNext").click()
```

If I manually enter my password everything works fine, but that defeats the purpose of automating this job.  Maybe there is a way to trick the system.  Not sure.

Comment: Based on your screenshot - this is an `<input>` element, and not `div` one.

Comment: Replace `password = wd.find_element_by_id("password")` with `password = wd.find_element_by_name("password")`

Comment: @Andersson - it worked!  Thanks so much.  I see my error.  I feel really dumb now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the image, it looks like you may want to `send_keys` to the input with `name` "password".

```
password = wd.find_element_by_name("password")
```